# How to copy file in amazon s3 Paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, aws-sdk

I have a model `Shop` which has a `logo`and it's stored in amazon s3, i want to copy it to another model `Company`, i'm doing simply:

```
shop = Shop.find(1)
company = Company.find(1)
company.logo = shop.logo
company.save!
```

but its giving an error:

```
[paperclip] copying logos/1/original/220px-Bart_Simpson.png to local file /tmp/dac9e3329951078b23c5deed39f3193120160107-30855-ivrdms.png
No Such Key - cannot copy logos/1/original/220px-Bart_Simpson.png to local file /tmp/dac9e3329951078b23c5deed39f3193120160107-30855-ivrdms.png
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/dac9e3329951078b23c5deed39f3193120160107-30855-nz0h5c.png'
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename 220px-Bart_Simpson.png (["image/png"]), content type discovered from file command: inode/x-empty. See documentation to allow this combination.

ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Logo has an extension that does not match its contents
```

Can somebody say what the hell is going on here, or how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try as, May I know which version of paperclip is being used.

```
shop = Shop.find(1)
company = Company.find(1)
company.logo = File.open(shop.logo.path, 'rb')
company.save!
```